# Is the pronoun "his" personal or possessive pronoun at following sentence:

Tags: pronouns

Mike gave Sarah the keys to his house. The website that I study claims that it is a personal pronoun. But since it is his house, should't it be possessive pronoun?

Comment: The genitive (possessive) pronouns are a subtype of personal pronouns.

Answer (score 1):

It will help knowing what language you're coming from.

Anyway, in the example *his house*, the word **his** is possessive. It is because it indicates ownership (possessive case).

Bonus:

The question should have been worded like this:

> Is the pronoun “his” **a** personal or possessive pronoun **in**
>   following sentence?

Since you're learning English, I thought you'd like to know...

Comment: It's probably good to note that *his* is both a personal pronoun and a possessive pronoun. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: You mean it is generally the case that "his" can be both personal and possessive pronoun, or in this sentence "his" is both personal and possessive pronoun? By the way thank you for your answers  and correction of my sentence.

Comment: There are personal pronouns, and some of them are possessive (it's a subcategory of personal pronouns). _He_ is a personal pronoun, _his_ is too. But _his_ is also a possessive personal pronoun.